# Havdalah before the proper time

Tags: halacha, shabbat, time, havdalah

The [Gemara Berachos 27b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Berakhot.27b.10?lang=bi) talks about making havdalah before the end of Shaabos:

> רַבִּי יֹאשִׁיָּה מְצַלֵּי שֶׁל מוֹצָאֵי שַׁבָּת בְּשַׁבָּת: אוֹמֵר הַבְדָּלָה עַל הַכּוֹס אוֹ אֵינוֹ אוֹמֵר הַבְדָּלָה עַל הַכּוֹס? תָּא שְׁמַע דְּאָמַר רַב יְהוּדָה אָמַר שְׁמוּאֵל: מִתְפַּלֵּל אָדָם שֶׁל מוֹצָאֵי שַׁבָּת בְּשַׁבָּת וְאוֹמֵר הַבְדָּלָה עַל הַכּוֹס.
>
> A similar dilemma was raised concerning the fact that Rabbi Yoshiya would pray the evening prayer of the conclusion of Shabbat on Shabbat: After praying, while it is still Shabbat, does he recite havdala over the cup of wine or does one not recite havdala over the cup of wine? Come and hear a resolution to this, as Rav Yehuda said that Shmuel said: One prays the evening prayer of the conclusion of Shabbat on Shabbat and recites havdala over the cup of wine.

As emphasized by the [codifiers](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.293.3?lang=bi), this is only is extenuating circumstances.  What is the halacha is one accidently said havdalah before the proper time? Does he need to say havdalah again?

Also, the [Shulchan Aruch (O.C. 293:3)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.293.3?lang=bi) says that one does not make the beracha on the candle when making havdalah early. Is that only when making havdalah very early, or could one make the beracha on a (previously lit) candle after sunset but still before the time for ending Shabbos, thus saving one who accidentally said havdalah early from having to repeat that beracha?